# How to perform long HTTP requests in expressjs?

Tags: http, express, request

I wrote an express.js application and one of my GET requests takes a very long time to complete (it runs a spark query on a Hadoop client).
Because the request takes so much time, the client which performed the request (Chrome, Firefox, jQuery) re-sends the same request to the express.js app again and again.
Is there a way to handle these recurring requests?

Answer (score 3):

The reason consecutive requests were made, was indeed due to request timeout.
I managed to make it work using the following on the request object: `req.connection.setTimeout(60*10*1000);`
So the full code would look like this:

```js
app.get('/timetunnel/:accountId/:date', (req, res) => {
    // this request takes a lot of time, so increase the timeout
    req.connection.setTimeout(60 * 10 * 1000);
    reallyLongOperation();  // preferably async to prevent server blocking
});
```

Comment: `req.connection` is now deprecated and can be replaced with `req.socket`

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this in your app.js file

```
var server = app.listen(port);

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(600 * 60 * 1000);
});
```

Also if you use any sort of proxy server, make sure it doesnt have timeout on requests aswell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still get the recurring requests. Is there anything else you think might help?

Comment: Do you use browsersync as your serving proxy ? I once had an timeout issue with him, wich was really annoying to debug. you can also try to set the timeout on the server variable